# Congratulations Richard U for a 100K!

Tags: discussion

Congratulations to Richard U for reaching 100K.

We are inspired by you. Wish you good fortune and the best it yet to come!!

*A personal note: In case you're yet to read the bio, [please do](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/46894/richard-u)*.

Comment: Came here as this post was spoiled into my timeline being hot, but unfortunately I don't understand what it's actually about and why Richard should retire now.

Comment: @leymannx 100k is a milestone, and I've stated in the past that I would step back once I hit it.  only... 6? of us have hit that high in rep.

Comment: @RichardU – Tanks for clarification. Don't step back.

Answer (score 18):

Well done Richard, you certainly put in the hard yards and earned it. I haven't always been in full agreement but you invariably have a valuable and valid perspective. I have always noticed that you think things through and get to the core of an issue, rather than focusing on symptom relief, which is an admirable way to look at problems.

Comment: If you ever start to agree with me too often, please seek professional help, it's the first sign you're not well.

Comment: I certainly will.... ahaha

Comment: Does that mean disagreeing with @RichardU means we are just fine?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek no, because a conditional statement is not logically equivalent to its inverse. Let P=We agree with Richard, and Q=we are not well. Also P -> Q... that does not mean that ~P -> ~Q so we can disagree with Richard and still be not well :P

Comment: However, using *modus tollens* we can have that P -> Q, then ~Q thus ~P ... so that means if we "are ok" we can conclude that we don't agree with Richard :)

Comment: This is one of my very few answers that hasn't (yet) garnered a downvote :O fan club must be out for the weekend.... hehe... think I'll look up modus tollens so I can get the joke

Comment: @DarkCygnus I was hoping to establish my wellness, and I suspected the logic wouldn't hold up.  Even worse, sometimes I agree with him! (first comment on his accepted answer: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/131025/quitting-employee-has-privileged-access-to-critical-information/)

Comment: @Kilisi hah... careful what you wish for lol... btw: [modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens)

Comment: @DarkCygnus yeah, I gave up after a couple of sentences, too many long words for me.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek I'd say a healthy percentage of disagreement would be 30-60%

Answer (score 16):

Way to go Richard, 100K is very impressive!

Retirement awaits!

Comment: Yeah, it's a changing world, and I've already gotten enough agist shade thrown my way to know it's time to step back soon.

Comment: @RichardU Yeah... about that... if you're going to complain about people "_throwing shade_" at you, we're going to have to rip up your old-enough-to-retire card.

Comment: Been watching too much youtube, LOL!

Answer (score 10):

You hung in there, and made it to 100k. Well done!
Good luck in whatever you do going forward.